Is it possible to have non-decoded values in a Decodable struct?
I have a "Course" struct that is used in decoding certain JSON values:
struct Course: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var name: String?
    var courseCode: String
    var id: Int
    var image_download_url: String?
    var term: Term?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case image_download_url
        case term
        case courseCode = "course_code"
    }
}

I would find it useful for the Course struct to also be able to store a value bgColor. Do I need to define a new struct that incorporates all of the data from Course as well as that bgColor?

...can't you just add a var bgColor: String? ?

@Dai adding that breaks compat with the Decodable protocol

You can implement Decodable such that your types are backwards (and forwards) compatible - unless that's outside your control? (e.g. see here: your CodingKeys don't have to be an exhaustive enum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126079/swift-decodable-nestedcontainer-and-backwards-compatibility )

I am a little lost on how to apply that CodingKeys as a struct example to my case. Does it make sense to use the one provided in that answer since I am accepting arbitrary Strings and Ints?

I don’t understand why you can’t use the CodingKeys enum you have above in your question and just add the property as suggested in the first comment? Why would that solution not work, why wouldn’t it be decodable?

@JoakimDanielson The bgColor property I want to add needs to be exempt from decoding. I get a decoding error when I add the property alongside a CodingKey.

But you shouldn’t modify the CodingKeys enum. Only add the property.

Then we're back to the same issue. Type 'Course' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

That’s not possible or I am completely misunderstanding what you’re saying

What is the value type of bgcolor? You may need to write your own init and encode methods if you want to store the value in the json. To use the default free init all of your properties must conform to codable specifically the codable portion

if you have var bgColor: Color? then you will get the error you show,
because Color is not Decodable. You need to create a custom struct
to hold the Color parameters. If you just add var bgColor: String? then
there is no reason for the error unless your Term is not Decodable.
